# How do you host images using Windows Server so that they are accessible over the internet?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I was trying to figure out a way to host images (picture images, not disk images) such that they are accessible over the internet via URLs--in a way similar to a web service like Photobucket or ImageShack.  I have a whole bunch of Windows Servers (Windows Server 2008 R2) available in the cloud.  Instead of hosting images using Photobucket or ImageShack, I wanted to host this images directly on my own Windows cloud.

This could be really complicated or really simple.  I have no idea, as I know very little about IIS 6 (which is what I am using) or web servers.  If this is too broad of a question (as there are probably multiple ways of implementing this), is there at least some guide or documentation of how someone else has setup image hosting?  Perhaps a step-by-step guide of at least one way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to architect solutions for you. You need to do some reading on the topic, and perhaps take some training classes. Once you have a firm grasp on the topic at hand, then come back if you have any specific questions about implementation. Asking us to architect an entire solution for you from scratch is really sort of disrespectful if you think about it.

Comment: Also, you say you're using IIS6 and Windows Server 2008 R2. That's impossible. If your Server OS is 2008 R2, you're using IIS 7.5.

Comment: @MDMarra I don't agree that asking for us to architect the solution for him is disrespectful.  It won't be particularly fruitful, but this might be a good time to mention to nairware that this is the type of thing a lot of SAs, such as the ones on ServerFault, do for a living, and can be enticed to do on a project-work basis.  Personally, I like these little green pieces of paper the government makes, and often do this kind of thing on the side in exchange for stacks of those little paper rectangles, and I'm not the only one on here who does the same.

Comment: This isn't a site to solicit consulting work. Also, this certainly falls into the"overly broad" categorization in the [faq]. To me, this is disrespectful, because it's like saying "I don't want to put the effort into learning this myself, can someone do it for me for free?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for a beginner would be to either just to put all the images in some folder and share that folder on web server, which is not really aesthetic.
Other option is to install wordpress an some gallery plugins on iis an then put images on it. Try searching Google  a little about wordpress and galleries. that seem like the easiest solution for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

If you have public IP address you could easily access your images over the Internet. I don't how you are going to access them i.e through browser or remote desktop. If you don't have public IP use dyn dns or other dns services so that you can access your machine. [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/)
is one good project if you wish to use web base access. Install it along with PHP and add a port forward on your router. Best of luck!